# telegram bot Отправка сообщений каждую минуту

Tags: php, telegram-bot, rss

есть один телеграм бот, который парсит rss ленту. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно проверять на наличие новых записей в rss и сразу отправлять сообщение в бота?

```
$bot->command('feed', function ($message) use ($bot) {
$url = 'url';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {

    $line_rss =  ' '.$item->title.' ';
    $line_rss .= ' '.$item->link.' ';
    $line_rss .= $item->pubDate;
    $line_rss .= ' <br>';
    break;
}
$bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $line_rss);
```

});

Comment: По крону раз в минуту запускаем скрипт. Тот парсит rss, и если есть новые сообщения (он помнит какое сообщение было последним), то посылает их через бот. Запоминает новое последние сообщение.

Comment: Не особо дружу с кроном, если честно. Вот я спарсил инфу, записал в переменную (это вынес в отдельный файлик)
Как мне его запускать в боте-то и как сравнивать?
При сравнении из бота я получаю строку, которую с чем сравнивать?

Comment: С кроном надо разобраться, главное чтобы демон крона был запущен. Как запоминать последний обработанный элемент rss? Или у каждого элемента есть возрастающий id, тогда просто запомнить этот ид и все элементы с ид больше запомненного ид будут новыми и их надо будет послать в бот. Если ид нет, но обновление скрипта происходит раз в несколько секунд, то можно использовать `$item->pubDate`. Как запомнить последний обработанный ид - пишем или в БД или в файл или в Redis.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю на каком этапе записывать в файл, а на каком проверять, если записывать после перебора rss, а проверять до, то никогда ничего печатать не будет ведь

Comment: Записывать в файл после каждой успешной обработки - разобрали rss, если там были новые сообщения, то отправили их и пишем в файл последний отправленный ид или дату.

Comment: а можно пример в коде, пожааалуйста? Не допирает никак
примерно по блокам

открываем рсс, проходимся по массиву, смотрим если pubDate == записанному в файле, то break, иначе выводим и записываем в файл, верно?

Comment: что за ресурс? вебхуки, не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно такая идея

```
// имя файла где храним последнюю дату с полным путем
$lastPubDateFileName = 'file_path/lastPubDate.txt';

$bot->command('feed', function ($message) use ($bot, $lastPubDateFileName) {
// флаг, что мы уже выставили последнюю дату в этом запуске скрипта
$bLastPubDateSet = false;

// берем данные из файла, правда его может изначально не быть
if (file_exists($lastPubDateFileName)) {
    $lastPubDate = file_get_contents($lastPubDateFileName);
} else {
    $lastPubDate = 0;
}

$url = 'url';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {

    // проверяем что дата из рсс больше даты из файла
    if (strtotime($item->pubDate) > strtotime($lastPubDate)) {
        $line_rss =  ' '.$item->title.' ';
        $line_rss .= ' '.$item->link.' ';
        $line_rss .= $item->pubDate;
        $line_rss .= ' <br>';

        $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $line_rss);

        // устанавливаем последнюю дату один раз - 
        // поскольку рсс отсортирован от самых свежих к старым, нам надо это сделать с первым
        if (!$bLastPubDateSet) {
            $bLastPubDateSet = true;
            file_put_contents($lastPubDateFileName, $item->pubDate);
        }
    } else {
        // если элемент уже был послан, то и все дальше были посланы, выходим
        break;
    }

}

});
```